# Piecewise function in a caption

Tags: captions

I need help putting my piecewise function in my caption. I have code for the caption - and code for the function, just need to put the jigsaw together - would be great if somebody could help me!

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.8]{Nolim.png}
  \caption{}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 




\[
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   -5 & \text{if $x<2$} \\
                                   x & \text{if $x>2$} \\
  \end{cases}
\]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your caption is

```
$\displaystyle f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   -5 & \text{if $x<2$} \\
                                   x & \text{if $x>2$} \\
  \end{cases}
$
```

you have the expected result.

Comment: it's not working for me - do i need a package?

Comment: If you use `\text`, the package `amsmath` is needed.